# Does anyone know this parable? King & peasant, possibly from Kierkegaard

Tags: kierkegaard, faith

I remember fragments of a parable—I think the point is that it's supposed to be an image of faith—and I think it's from Kierkegaard, though I have no idea if that's true, or where in Kierkegaard it might be from (I have not read much that the man wrote). So my question is: does anyone recognize this and/or know its source?

What I remember of the parable: there's a king and a peasant. In the dead of night, the king visits the peasant and has some kind of meaningful interaction with him. No witnesses other than the two of them. The king returns to the castle before dawn and there's no evidence. The peasant doubts his memory, etc. The point is, I think, related to how the peasant must believe this actually happened, even in the face of a total lack of evidence and the whole *prima facie* implausibility of the event.

Sorry it's not much to go off of. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Kierkegaard has a parable of the king and the maiden which shares some features with what you mentioned.  It is difficult to find in a complete, original form because it has been adopted by a variety of religious groups that only excerpt it.

It can be found here:  https://antilogicalism.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/philosophical-fragments.pdf p14